# Use regular expression to mask last 4 digit in Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to mask the last 4 digits of the identity number (hkid)
A123456(7) -> A123***(*)

I can do this by below:

```
hkid.replaceAll("\\d{3}\\(\\d\\)", "***(*)")
```

However, can my regular expression really can match the last 4 digit and replace by "*"?

```
hkid.replaceAll(regex, "*")
```

Please help, thanks.

Jessie

Comment: What's the problem with your expression? The fact that it would fail for `A12345(67)`?

Comment: Hi Thomas, as my program should provide flexibility for masking different pattern with "*" (I am sorry I do not mentioned this clearly in my question).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't do it with regular expressions:

```
char[] cs = hkid.toCharArray();
for (int i = cs.length - 1, d = 0; i >= 0 && d < 4; --i) {
  if (Character.isDigit(cs[i])) {
    cs[i] = '*';
    ++d;
  }
}
String masked = new String(cs);
```

This goes from the end of the string, looking for digit characters, which it replaces with a `*`. Once it's found 4 (or reaches the start of the string), it stops iterating, and builds a new string.

Comment: Doing it that way might require a bit more code but is probably easier to understand and faster as well.

Comment: @Thomas agreed. I think that regexes are too often viewed as "the only way" to manipulate strings, and you can easily end up with an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Hi Andy, as my program should provide flexibility for masking different pattern with "*" (I am sorry I do not mentioned this clearly in my question), your solution is great, however, not suit my situation, anyway, thanks~ =)

Comment: This approach will mask the last four digits in any string.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that a non-regex solution is probably the simplest and fastest, here's a regex to catch the last 4 digits independent if there is a grouping ot not: `\d(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3}\D*$)`

This expression is meant to match any digit that is followed by 0 to 3 digits before hitting the end of the input.

A short breakdown of the expression:

- `\d` matches a single digit
- `\D` matches a single non-digit
- `(?=...)` is a positive look-ahead that contributes to the match but isn't consumed
- `(?:...){0,3}` is a non-capturing group with a quantity of 0 to 3 occurences given.
- `$` matches the end of the input

So you could read the expression as follows: "match a single digit if it is followed by a sequence of 0 to 3 times any number of non-digits which are followed by a single digit and that sequence is followed by any number of non-digits and the end of the input" (sounds complicated, no?).

Some results when using `input.replaceAll( "\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){0,3}\\D*$)", "*" )`:

- input = "A1234567" -> output = "A123****"
- input = "A123456(7)" -> output = "A123***(*)"
- input = "A12345(67)" -> output = "A123**(**)"
- input = "A1(234567)" -> output = "A1(23****)"
- input = "A1234B567" -> output = "A123*B***"

As you can see in the last example the expression will match digits only. If you want to match letters as well either replace `\d` and `\D` with `\w` and `\W` (note that `\w` matches underscores as well) or use custom character classes, e.g. `[02468]` and `[^02468]` to match even digits only.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry for your loss ;) - One could now argue whether that expression while shorter than your code is more understandable or not. It probably depends on the audience, i.e. regex experts might call it trivial while others probably won't.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your advice. Your solution work great!! =)